# Migration of data from Ali cloud to linux aws-ec2 tableau server

Tags: tableau-api, migrate

I want to migrate all data from tableau server hosted on ali cloud to the server launched on aws ec2 but i am not able to find resources how to import and export that data
Could anyone help?

Comment: Save a backup of your current Tableau server and then restore that backup on your ec2.

Comment: Hii @Bernado thanks for the response could you please elaborate on that , or maybe share some source that because i cannot find much stuff related to Ali cloud

Comment: Check tableau's docs backup and restore section. https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/db.htm

Comment: Hi @bernardo This is for windows and i want to migrate data for tableau server installed on Ali cloud ECS instance ,Is the process  same for this as well??